# Alloy constraint specification

Tags: logic, alloy, logic-programming

I wrote the following code block in Alloy:

```
one h: Human | h in s.start => {
    s'.currentCall = h.from
}
```

I want to pick one 'human' from a set of humans (s.start) and set a variable (s'.currentCall) equal to h.from.
However I think this code is saying: There is only one human in s.start, where

```
s'.currentCall = h.from
```

is true.
Is my assumption correct? And how should I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, the meaning of the `one` quantifier is that there is exactly one element in the given domain (set) such that the quantifier body holds true.

Regarding your original goal of picking one element from a set and **setting** its field value to something: that sounds like an imperative update, and you can't really do that directly in Alloy; Alloy is fully declarative, so you can only assert logical statements about the sets and relations for a bounded universe of discourse.

If you just change `one` to `some` and also change the implication to conjunction, and then run the analysis (a simple `run` command to find a valid instance), the Alloy Analyzer will find a model in which the value `s'.currentCall` is equal to `h.from` for some (arbitrary) `h` from `s.start`:

```
pred p[s, s': S] {
  some h: s.start | s'.currentCall = h.from
}

run p
```

I hope this is what you want to achieve.